# navigation bar isn't responsive

Tags: html, css, navigationbar, menubar

This is my HTML and CSS code I want to make the navigation bar responsive but the media query doesn't cooperate It doesn't make any difference. and #menu doesn't make any difference in the first place(`display: none` doesn't work) it also doesn't work under media query. I can't figure out why, please help me.

```css
.header .icons a {
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 2.5rem;
color: #333;
margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

header .icons a:hover {
color: black;
}

#menu {
display: none;
}

@media(max-width:991px) {
html {
font-size: 55%;
}
.header {
padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
}
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
#menu {
display: inline-block;
}
.header .navbar {
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
right: 0;
background-color: black;
width: 30rem;
height: calc(100vh - 9.5rem);
}
.header .navbar a {
color: white;
display: block;
margin: 1.5rem;
padding: .5rem;
font-size: 2rem;
}
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
<title>jj </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<header class="header" >
<a href="#" class="logo">
<img src="images/logo.jpg" alt=""></a>
<nav class="navbar">
<a href="#home">home</a>
<a href="#products">varieties</a>
<a href="#about us">about us</a>
<a href="#contact us">contact us</a>
</nav>

<div class="icons">
<a href="#" class="fas fa-bars" id="menu"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a head element with a meta tag at the beginning of your code so the website is properly rendered based on actual lower screen sizes (without this, websites tend to render in higher resolution sizes than the device actually is).

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

I also cannot find where your header class is used in your html code so I got rid of most of the .header portions in your media queries to have the styling take effect.

```
    @media(max-width:991px){
        html{
            font-size: 55%;
        }
        .header{
            padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
        }
    }
    @media(max-width:768px){
        #menu { 
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .navbar{
            position: absolute;
            top:100px; right: 0;
            background-color:#333;
            width: 30rem;
            height: calc(100vh - 9.5rem);
        }
        .navbar a{
            color:rgb(243, 215, 215);
            display: block;
            margin:1.5rem;
            padding:.5rem;
            font-size:2rem;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly just exchange your nav with this template and it should work perfectly.

```css
@media(max-width:991px) {
    html {
    font-size: 55%;
    }
    .header {
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    }
    }
    
@media(max-width:768px) {
    .topnav {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}


.topnav {
    background-color: gray;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: light-gray;
    color: red;
    transition: 1s;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="topnav">
        <a href="#home">home</a>
        <a href="#varieties">varieties</a>
        <a href="#about us">about us</a>
        <a href="#contact us">contact us</a>
    </div>
```